# Label text not updating one by one Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, label

I have this custom class

```
Public Class labelScroll
    Inherits Label

    Public Shadows Property Text As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Dim add As String = ""
            Dim result As String()
            Dim i As Integer
            result = Split(value, vbLf)
            Dim n As Integer = 30
            If (result.Length < n) Then
                n = result.Length
            End If
            Dim start As Integer = result.Length - n
            For i = start To result.Length - 1 Step 1
                add += result(i) + Environment.NewLine
            Next
            MyBase.Text = add
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I have a form that I placed this labelScroll on and also placed a button: I have this code for the button's click event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    LabelScroll1.Text = "1"
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    LabelScroll1.Text += "2"
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    LabelScroll1.Text += "3"
End Sub
```

What happens when I click the button is that it takes 2 seconds and then just shows "1" "2" "3" on three lines. What actually should happen is that when the user clicks the button, "1" appears and then `Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` is executed so the program waits for 1 second then prints "2" on the next line.

Why isn't this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the text on a label invalidates the control - meaning it will redraw the next time the event queue is processed (effectively).  This won't happen whilst you're sleeping on the UI thread - try adding `MyBase.Update()` immediately after the MyBase.Text = ... line to force an immediate update.

Comment: No problem - glad to have been of help!